# Multiple ether wallet to single wallet

Tags: transactions

I have a lot of ether wallet . How can i send all my ether to single wallet. I cant to send single to single it will take a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to transfer from many accounts to a single account, right?
If you don't want to do it manually, you can import all your keystores to geth and script the transfer in the web3 console.

Assumed that you have MEW keystores, you can do the following:

#### WARNING: I didn't test this code. Be very careful with your mainnet ether. If you don't understand what the code below is doing, don't just copy&paste it.

1. Install geth and sync with the network `geth --fast --cache=1024`
2. Copy all your wallet files to geht's `<DATADIR>/keystore` - now you have all your mew accounts accessible via geth
3. `geth attach` after the sync
4. a) If you have same password for all your wallets, unlock all accounts with `eth.accounts.forEach(function(a){personal.unlockAccount(a, "<PASSWORD>")})`, b) if each account has a different password, you'll have to unlock it one by one.
5. `var gasPrice = web3.toWei(3, 'gwei')` - eventually it works with 2gwei too, check https://ethgasstation.info for the current safe gasPrice
6. On the console `eth.accounts.forEach(function(a){eth.sendTransaction({from:a, to:<TARGET_ACCOUNT>, value:eth.getBalance(a)-(21000*gasPrice), gas:21000, gasPrice:gasPrice})})` - replace  with the address of your target account.

Comment: Yes i dont want to do manually how can i do this . Can you explain more please?

Comment: How do you store your private keys? Encrypted wallet files?

Comment: Keystore file . I created with mew

Comment: I've extended the answer. Be very careful with your mainnet ether! Test first with one account and a small transfer value.

Comment: I have other coin too how i transfer them?

Comment: Erc20 coin in mew

Comment: I cant see your comment

Comment: I have so many account i cant do it manually

Comment: With ERC20 tokens you'll have to import the ABI and call the transfer function on the corresponding contract instance. It would require some more code. You can open a new question for this.